# After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 not able to install any new package

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 LTS but after upgrading errors appear after installing any software. I tried to install `icedtea-netx`. Generally following error comes

```
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/45TeXinputs.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/55Fonts.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/65BibTeX.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/75DviPS.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/85Misc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/90TeXDoc.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/95NonPath.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.K0LdoKUQ
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Does this listing contain updmap.cfg?

1. `ls /etc/texmf/web2c/`

If so issue a:

2. `nano -w /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`
3. Comment the following line by adding a `#`, like so:
   `#Map ua1.map`
   Now repair the error:
4. `sudo updmap-sys`

See the associated [bug over on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1017675)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your software source list? Goto terminal and write `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and check if your software source is something close to this

http://pastebin.com/zzLJKD4k

Comment: The sources list should have been updated by the Distribution Upgrade.  Please don't confuse the OP's issue.